# Meteor, GitHub API : how do I get GitHub gravatar profile photo as property?

Tags: api, github, meteor, gravatar

I get

```
    {{profile.name}} : {{services.github.email}}
```

for my Meteor app using GitHub API, but I can't find the profile photo property with Meteor.user() command. It seems like GitHub has its photo from Gravatar. How do I get the profile photo like I did for username and email address  {{profile.name}} : {{services.github.email}}

My app is similar to this

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/13/build-app-45-minutes-meteor/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932422/get-github-avatar-from-email-or-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gravatar as well, based on the email address. [It's pretty easy – see the documentation.](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/)