# Get username and avatar url through github authenticaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, github-api

I am using the oauth gem to authenticate users through GitHub.  I'm trying to get the person's username and avatar url.  I can't find, or completely missed, where in the scopes I can get access to these things.  This is from my user model and my initializer file:

```
# omniauth.rb
scope: "user, public_repo, repo"

# user.rb
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
  end
end
```

I have tried guessing what might get the username and avatar url with:

```
user.username = auth["info"]["login"]
user.avatar = auth["info"]["avatar_url"]
```

Comment: Try to print `auth` variable (i.e. use `p auth` or write it to log) and find appropriate fields.

Comment: did that and the fields are "login" and "avatar_url" as i thought but they still show up as nil in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return their username: `auth.info.nickname`

Also you can use this api to get avatars from the github api:

[Get GitHub avatar from email or name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932422/get-github-avatar-from-email-or-name)